# In Griddle-react component. I am changing resultsPerPage props with wrapper component but it is not getting updated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, griddle

```
<div>
 <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
 <Griddle results={data} resultsPerPage={this.state.pageSize}
</div>

handleChange(e){
this.setState({
  pageSize: e.target.value
)}
```

State of pagesize is getting updated . I have checked in console. But griddle table is not getting updated.

Comment: please provide code of Griddle component

Comment: It is working fine now when i upgraded to "griddle-react": "^0.6.1" . Thanks for showing concern.